# jQuery, onclick add 0.99 cent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want that if a button is clicked, 0.99 will be added to my var amount. I cant get this done and i dont know why. Anyone an idea?

```
var amount = 0;
    $('.factuur-post').click(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            var amount = 0.99++;
        }

    });
    console.log(amount);
```

Comment: try `amount += 0.99;`

Comment: Take a look at the JavaScript expressions and operators basics here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Assignment_operators

Comment: How can i round it to 2 digits after the point? Now i get 2.969999999

Comment: @DonnyvanV Use `.toFixed(2);`

Comment: How does i have to work that out in my code?

Comment: @DonnyvanV i had already updated that in my answer.

Comment: `amount=amount.toFixed(2);`

Answer (score 2):

Use `var amount += 0.99;` instead of using `var amount = 0.99++;`

Try,

```
    var amount = 0;

    $('.factuur-post').click(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            var amount += parseFloat(0.99);
        }

    });

    console.log(amount.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: I get this error coming up: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +=

Comment: try `amount += parseFloat(0.99);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var amount = 0;
    $('.factuur-post').click(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            var amount += parseFloat(0.99);
        }

    });
   console.log(amount);
```

[parseFloat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
 amount += 0.99;
```

The problem with your code is that your doing a post increment which means you will increment after the assignment. This means you won't see the effects of the increment in the amount variable.

```
var amount = 0;
    $('.factuur-post').click(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
           amount += 0.99;
        }

    });
    console.log(amount);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var amount = 0;
$('.factuur-post').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var amount += 0.99;
    }

});
console.log(amount);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var amount = 0;
    $(function(){           
        $('.factuur-post').click(function(){
            if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                 amount = amount + 0.99;
            }
            console.log(amount);
        });
        console.log(amount);

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`var amount = 0.99++;`

doesn't work.

What `++` does is increment a `var` by 1.

In your code `0.99` isn't a variable, therefore it can't increment it. And even if it could, `amount` would *always* be equal to `1.99` (0.99 + 1 = 1.99).

So to fix it, you need to increment a variable. Except you're not incrementing by 1, you're incrementing by 0.99, so don't use `++` here.

Just use:

`amount += 0.99`

That means `amount = amount + 0.99`